# How to parse multiple JSON values into a string array?

Tags: c#, json

I'm making using of the pokeapi to learn about APIs but im faced with this issue.

The JSON data has multiple children values within its parent. I need to parse the value "type" from all these children .

I tried printing just the first value in that it encounters but i receive an error of 'int32 array index expected'

I also then tried making my variable "type" a string[] type but then it breaks my current code. I get the error Argument 3: cannot convert from 'string' to 'string[]'

Building the object

```cs
  PokeItem pokeItem = new PokeItem(name: $"{dataObj["name"]}",
          sprite: $"{dataObj["sprites"]["front_default"]}",
          type:$"{dataObj["types"]["type"]["name"]}",
          pokedexid:$"{dataObj["id"]}");
```

'Model' Class

```cs
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Sprite { get; set; }
    public string[] Type { get; set; }
    public string pokedexID { get; set; }

        public PokeItem(string name, string sprite, string[] type, string pokedexid )
        {
            Name = name;
            Sprite = sprite;
            Type = type;
            pokedexID = pokedexid;
        }
```

JSON That i am using

```
    "types": [
        {
            "slot": 2,
            "type": {
                "name": "poison",
                "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/4/"
            }
        },
        {
            "slot": 1,
            "type": {
                "name": "bug",
                "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/7/"
            }
        }
    ],
```

Expected Results: Be able to take all 'type' values and add them to the dataObj where i can access them later.

Actual Results:

> Error : int32 array index expected

OR

> Argument 3: cannot convert from 'string' to 'string[]'

Comment: Can you show me your full JSON string. The one that you have posted now is not a valid string

Comment: @RahulSharma I've Tried to add all the JSON data but it just crashes my browser. If you use postman, look at the data through that http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/15

Comment: What is `dataObj` exactly, and how did you create it? Are you trying to manually parse the JSON? Why not use something like JSON.NET to deserialise it directly into an object structure?

Comment: P.S. If you want to stick with dataObj then in order to read the first value (as you mentioned) I'd guess you maybe need to do something like `dataObj["types"][0]["type"]["name"]` so that you reference the first index of the "types" array. Otherwise it doesn't know which item in the list you're talking about. But if you want to read all types you'll need to do something more complex. Like I said, why not use a proper deserialiser?

Comment: ...to make that easier, a site like http://json2csharp.com/ can help you easily create the necessary object structure by pasting in the JSON sample.

Comment: @ADyson That has printed the first value (thank you), i assume i just need to loop the for each value within the parent?

Comment: @ADyson, i'm trying to stay away from anything that does it for me right now. But i appreciate you showing me that i will keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: Yes you would need to loop them in order to create the array of type strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specific to your `JSON` string that you have posted, you can refer to the following code snippet to deserialize your string into its respective components.I am using the `Newtonsoft JSON` library which is a popular high-performance `JSON` framework for .NET.

Since your JSON string is too long to be posted here, so I am giving you a link where you can find the JSON string and its associated Model for parsing. The link can be found [HERE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/apCCU5)

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json="Your json string from the URL";
        
        var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

        Console.WriteLine(response.sprites);
        Console.WriteLine(response.base_experience);

        foreach(var value in response.abilities)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value.ability.name);
            Console.WriteLine(value.ability.url);
        }
    }
}

public class Ability2
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Ability
{
    public Ability2 ability { get; set; }
    public bool is_hidden { get; set; }
    public int slot { get; set; }
}

public class Form
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Version
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class GameIndice
{
    public int game_index { get; set; }
    public Version version { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Version2
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class VersionDetail
{
    public int rarity { get; set; }
    public Version2 version { get; set; }
}

public class HeldItem
{
    public Item item { get; set; }
    public List<VersionDetail> version_details { get; set; }
}

public class Move2
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class MoveLearnMethod
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class VersionGroup
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class VersionGroupDetail
{
    public int level_learned_at { get; set; }
    public MoveLearnMethod move_learn_method { get; set; }
    public VersionGroup version_group { get; set; }
}

public class Move
{
    public Move2 move { get; set; }
    public List<VersionGroupDetail> version_group_details { get; set; }
}

public class Species
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Sprites
{
    public string back_default { get; set; }
    public object back_female { get; set; }
    public string back_shiny { get; set; }
    public object back_shiny_female { get; set; }
    public string front_default { get; set; }
    public object front_female { get; set; }
    public string front_shiny { get; set; }
    public object front_shiny_female { get; set; }
}

public class Stat2
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Stat
{
    public int base_stat { get; set; }
    public int effort { get; set; }
    public Stat2 stat { get; set; }
}

public class Type2
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Type
{
    public int slot { get; set; }
    public Type2 type { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Ability> abilities { get; set; }
    public int base_experience { get; set; }
    public List<Form> forms { get; set; }
    public List<GameIndice> game_indices { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public List<HeldItem> held_items { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public bool is_default { get; set; }
    public string location_area_encounters { get; set; }
    public List<Move> moves { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int order { get; set; }
    public Species species { get; set; }
    public Sprites sprites { get; set; }
    public List<Stat> stats { get; set; }
    public List<Type> types { get; set; }
    public int weight { get; set; }
}
```

Running this on my Visual Studio yields an example output like:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was a little confused initially  because it said just sprites, i assume if you had written sprites.front_default that would have given you the url to the sprite? 

Also i assume this is the more sensible way of working with JSON and public rest APIs?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I find this method the best and most efficient to work with JSON strings. I hoped this helped you out.